# Dashed author duplicates and apalike

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I use bibtex, natbib (author-year), and the apalike-style.
Is there any option to replace authors with a dash in the references list at the end of the document if there are two publications by the same authors in one year, e.g., Authors (1999a) and Authors (1999b)

Best
F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can steal the code for dashed names from `IEEEtran.bst`.

The heart of the "dahsed" feature is the function

```
FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
{ 's :=
   oldname empty$
     { s 'oldname := s }
     { s oldname =
         { "---" }
         { s 'oldname := s }
       if$
     }
   if$
}
```

A call to that function needs to be added after each function call that would print the primary name of an entry.

The necessary changes to turn `apalike.bst` into `apalike-dashed.bst` are

```
--- apalike.bst 2010-12-10 10:19:51.000000000 +0100
+++ apalike-dashed.bst  2019-01-28 17:29:20.877333300 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,9 @@
+%% apalike-dashed.bst
+%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472240/35864
+%% 2019-01-28 MW
+%% modification of apalike.bst with dashed functionality from IEEEtran.bst
+%% original header follows
+%% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 % BibTeX `apalike' bibliography style (version 0.99a, 8-Dec-10), adapted from
 % the `alpha' style, version 0.99a; for BibTeX version 0.99a.
 %
@@ -76,7 +82,7 @@
   #3 'after.block :=
 }

-STRINGS { s t }
+STRINGS { s t oldname }

 FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
 { 's :=
@@ -479,9 +485,22 @@
   " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
 }

+FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
+{ 's :=
+   oldname empty$
+     { s 'oldname := s }
+     { s oldname =
+         { "---" }
+         { s 'oldname := s }
+       if$
+     }
+   if$
+}
+
 FUNCTION {article}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
+  name.or.dash
   author format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
@@ -504,9 +523,11 @@
 { output.bibitem
   author empty$
     { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
+      name.or.dash
       editor format.key output
     }
     { format.authors output.nonnull
+      name.or.dash
       crossref missing$
         { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
         'skip$
@@ -537,6 +558,7 @@
 FUNCTION {booklet}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors output
+  name.or.dash
   author format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
@@ -553,9 +575,11 @@
 { output.bibitem
   author empty$
     { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
+      name.or.dash
       editor format.key output
     }
     { format.authors output.nonnull
+      name.or.dash
       crossref missing$
         { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
         'skip$
@@ -588,6 +612,7 @@
 FUNCTION {incollection}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
+  name.or.dash
   author format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
@@ -615,6 +640,7 @@
 FUNCTION {inproceedings}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
+  name.or.dash
   author format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
@@ -644,6 +670,7 @@
 FUNCTION {manual}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors output
+  name.or.dash
   author format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
@@ -660,6 +687,7 @@
 FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
+  name.or.dash
   author format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
@@ -676,6 +704,7 @@
 FUNCTION {misc}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors output
+  name.or.dash
   author format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
@@ -690,6 +719,7 @@
 FUNCTION {phdthesis}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
+  name.or.dash
   author format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
@@ -706,6 +736,7 @@
 FUNCTION {proceedings}
 { output.bibitem
   format.editors output
+  name.or.dash
   editor format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
@@ -724,6 +755,7 @@
 FUNCTION {techreport}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
+  name.or.dash
   author format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
@@ -740,6 +772,7 @@
 FUNCTION {unpublished}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
+  name.or.dash
   author format.key output                              % special for
   output.year.check                                     % apalike
   new.block
```

You can download `apalike-dashed.bst` from https://gist.github.com/moewew/fe37f610e010abb45ac14f4f318393f3

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby:a,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service I},
  year    = {1980},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
}
@book{appleby:b,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service II},
  year    = {1980},
  publisher = {Clarendon Press},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby:a,appleby:b}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-dashed}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Appleby, H. (1980a). On the Importance of the Civil Service I. Oxford University Press.//— (1980b). On the Importance of the Civil Service II. Clarendon Press.]

---

If you want the dash only for same author and same year, you could use

```
FUNCTION {name.or.dash}
{ 's :=
   oldname empty$
     { s 'oldname :=
       year 'oldyear :=
       s }
     { s oldname =
       year oldyear =
       and
         { "---" }
         { s 'oldname :=
           year 'oldyear :=
           s }
       if$
     }
   if$
}
```

instead of the definition above and you would have to declare the new variable `oldyear`

```
STRINGS { s t oldname oldyear }
```

I have never seen a style that only replaces authors from the same year, so I would not recommend doing that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is almost exactly what I needed! Is there any possibility to get dashed authors only if two publications are from the same year?

Comment: @Fabian That would be extremely unusual. But I'll see what I can do. I can't promise anything, though.

Comment: Thanks for the hint... Thought that's what the journal wants as they explicitly give an example with two publications of the same year. However, they remain mute on what happens to publications of different years. So no need to make any further changes then! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. The official APA style doesn't use that format, and so none of the conforming (`apacite`, `biblatex-apa`) or semi-conforming (`apalike`) APA styles will support it either. Assuming you're using `apalike` because you need a basic author-year style, you might want to switch to `biblatex`, where the option `[style=authoryear]` implements this style by default.  There will be minor differences between the styles that can be fixed quite easily. For more information see:

- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693)
- [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/2693).

Comment: I will definitely consider this the next time! Thanks a lot!